# Trying to change digit month ('01') to written month ('January')

Tags: javascript

Trying to work with this API which only gives month option as digit and simply trying to convert it to the name of the month. (01 for January etc). How do I convert the output?

```
function sortKey(api_data) {
  Logger.log('sortKey called with: ');
  var sort_key = '';
  var authors = api_data['contributors'];
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  var source = api_data['source'];
  switch (source) {
    case 'book':
    sort_key += stripArticlesFromTitle(api_data["pubnonperiodical"]["title"]);
    sort_key += api_data['pubnonperiodical']['year'];
    break;
    case 'journal':
    sort_key += stripArticlesFromTitle(api_data["journal"]["title"]);
    sort_key += api_data['pubjournal']['year'];
    var x =  Number(api_data['pubjournal']['month']) - 1;
    sort_key += monthNames[x];
    sort_key += api_data['pubjournal']['day'];
    break;
    case 'website':
    sort_key += stripArticlesFromTitle(api_data["website"]["title"]);
    break;
  }
  Logger.log(sort_key);
  return sort_key;
}
```

The HTML code for the outputs:

```
<td>
{{data.pubjournal.title}} - {{data.pubjournal.month}} / {{data.pubjournal.year}}
</td>
```

Current example output:

```
Trajectory Analysis and Rocket Design -
Rocket Propulsion - 02 / 2019
```

Ideal example output:

```
Trajectory Analysis and Rocket Design -
Rocket Propulsion - February / 2019
```

Comment: this seems correct
`var x =  Number(api_data['pubjournal']['month']) - 1;`
what is an example of data in `api_data['pubjournal']['month'] `?

Comment: 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11 or 12

Comment: You'll need to provide actual input inside your question, which produces the problem.

Comment: It should work if the data match the description. The code is correct for that scenario. Most likely the data is not what you describe. Please post a sample `api_data` which exhibits the problem.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: The HTML seems unrelated to the function. Where do you assign the month name to `data.pubjournal.month`?

Comment: Do not tell us how you use it. post the actual object named `api_data` that is the parameter of the `sortKey`. Log it with `console.log` or through your logger with `JSON.stringify(api_data, null,2);` and post it in your question.

Answer (score -2):

change

```
var x =  Number(api_data['pubjournal']['month']) - 1;
```

with

```
var x =  parseInt(api_data['pubjournal']['month']) - 1;
```

Comment: Why would that be a solution?